# How can I capture the enter key in Firefox 3.5 and redirect the page using Window.Location?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, dom-events

I am trying to implement a search functionality that is capturing the enter key and redirecting to a different page in an ASP.NET 3.5 application. Unfortunately it does not work in Firefox (version 3.5) but in IE it is working perfectly. Please see the following code:

#### Script:

```
function searchKeyPress(e) {
  if (window.event) { e = window.event; }
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
  }
}
function redirect() {
  document.location = "http://localhost:5555/search.aspx?q=keyword";
}
```

#### Markup:

```
  <form name="form1" method="post" runat="server" id="form1"/>
     <input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);"/>
     <input type="button" id="btnSearch" Value="Search" onclick="redirect();"/>
  </form/>
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just rename `txtSearch` to `q` and make the form `method="get"`? Why this roundabout way of hitting a search page?

Comment: But I have other form controls, if I use get method that will be showing all the values in query string in the url

Comment: No JavaScript is required for this at all.  This functionality is built into HTML for free.  See this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785425/javascript-problem-with-location-href/1785663#1785663

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a Submit button along with a form action to take you to the search page? The submit button exhibits the behavior you are looking for by default, so there is no need for javascript.

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="/search.aspx" id="form1"/>
    <input type="text" id="q" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" Value="Search" />
</form/>
```

If you really want to stick with your javascript solution (which I don't recommend because it is less accessible and relys on javascript) give this a try

```
function searchKeyPress(e) {
  e = e || window.event || event;
  var code = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == 13) {
    redirect();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Well I am looking some thing a page redirection with Query String values (similar to get method) I don't need a full form post

Comment: Give this a try, the `get` method will post the values in the querystring.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function searchKeyPress(e) {
        if (window.event) { e = window.event; }
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById('form1').submit();
        }
    }
    function redirect() {
       document.location = "http://localhost:5555/search.aspx?q=keyword";
    }
</script>
```

Use forms.submit() instead of .click(), .click() is only supported on ie, submit is supported in firefox also.